# to debug this project you must enable sql/clr

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

i am running a script from visual studio 2008 to a sql server 2008 connection

i am getting this message when i build:

```
to debug this project you must enable sql/clr debugging for the connection. note that during debugging all managed threads on the server will stop.
```

is this dangerous to do given that i have other databases on this server?

i am working on a particular database that is just a test database - does this msg mean all the other databases on this server might be affected as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should certainly be careful enabling this. As noted in [How to: Enable CLR Debugging For a Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165039(v=VS.90).aspx):

> A message box appears with the
>   warning: "SQL CLR debugging will cause
>   all managed threads on the server to
>   stop. Do you want to continue?". When
>   you are debugging SQL CLR database
>   objects, breaking execution will break
>   all threads on the server, affecting
>   other users. For this reason, you
>   should not debug SQL CLR applications
>   on a production server.

Comment: thanks! i am working on a particular database that is just a test database - does this msg mean all the other databases on this server might be affected as well?

Comment: Yes, I believe this will affect all threads on the server, regardless of which database they are connected to.